# How is a permutation composed of one cycle the product of disjoint cycles?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations, finite-groups, symmetric-groups

I'm reading through an abstract algebra textbook, and one of the exercises is as follows:

> Prove that every permutation in $S_n$ is the product of disjoint cycles.

I tried to figure it out on my own, but I got stuck on the special case in which a permutation is a single cycle (e.g. $(1 2 3)$ in $S_3$), since it cannot be disjoint with any other cycle in that permutation group, and you need two elements to perform multiplication. I thought maybe it would be disjoint from the empty set, but then multiplication is not well defined.

I ended up finding a proof [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2478207/983917), but it doesn't seem to consider the special case. I also tried looking this question up online, but I can't find any examples of it being asked before. The closest thing I can find is [this wiki page](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Cycle_decomposition_for_permutations), which just says that a cycle is a permutation.

So, my question is as follows:
Is a permutation composed of one cycle a product of disjoint cycles even if there is no multiplication? If so, how?

Comment: Which textbook are you referring to?

Comment: The textbook is "Abstract Algebra" by Herstein, and I'm also using the course materials for the Modern Algebra (18.703) course from MIT Open CourseWare. @Shaun

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're on the right track conceptually when you say it is "disjoint from the empty set." This isn't exactly how to phrase it, but the sentiment is there: it is disjoint from all the other cycles, because there are no other cycles.

This is how I would phrase it: a permutation $p$ is the product of disjoint cycles if, for some $n$, $p$ can be written as $p=\prod_{i=1}^nc_i$ where each $c_i$ is a cycle, and $c_i$ and $c_j$ are disjoint when $i\ne j$.

So, is $(123)$ a product of disjoint cycles? Let's test: is there an $n$ and a set of cycles $c_i$ so that $(123)=\prod_{i=1}^nc_i$? Sure: $n=1$ and $c_1=(123)$.

Comment: Thanks! Your formulation makes much more sense than the one I found, and cleanly deals with the base case.